# Is there a rounding algorithm that undoes base 2 conversion and infers precision? *hopefully in java*

Tags: java, rounding

If I have a number like 3.01 the computer seems to think the best double is the 64 bit number:

```
3.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625
```

Is there some way better than looking for say more than four 9's or 0's that I can generically  "round" to the precise base 10 representation?

Is there an algo that would take that 3.00999999... mess and return 3.01 WITHOUT me specifying that I want that precision.

I think most of the numbers I'm dealing with should be small enough that 64-bits will not have ambiguities.

Comment: The short answer is that you're not going to easily get what you want here. Floats are imprecise by their nature. See [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) on floating point numbers. If you just want to display it to a given precision, try sprintf.

Comment: @ChrisHeald: I wouldn't say that floats are imprecise per se - I'd say that the conversion from a decimal representation to a binary representation can lose information.

Comment: In a word, no. However, if you explained what you were hoping to achieve with this, we might be able to give better answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair point. Better said than I did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - because presumably you *might* have actually specified 3.0099999999999997868 as the input number, and wouldn't want that same value to be rounded to 3.01. Basically, you've lost information when converting from a decimal value to binary floating point - you can't get that information back.

If you're interested in decimal values rather than just the magnitude, you should consider using `BigDecimal` instead of `double`. (What do these values represent?)

EDIT: As noted by other answers, Java will give you 3.01 anyway when you just use `toString`, however you came to the original value. This is specified in `Double.toString`:

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double. That is, suppose that x is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument d. Then d must be the double value nearest to x; or if two double values are equally close to x, then d must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of d must be 0.

If that's good enough for you, it'll make life easier... but it sounds like you should be thinking about it more fundamentally.

Comment: I thought using jScience would help me store weights precisely, but all the methods return doubles even if I haven't converted the units.

Comment: I am not sure you can use BigDecimal without having to deal with precision at some point.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. But you certainly need to think about it when performing arithmetic, yes.

Comment: @Mikey: A weight isn't a precise thing to start with - it's going to be measured, so you haven't got *exactly* 3.01kg (or whatever you're measuring it in) to start with. Weight is an appropriate thing to use `double` for; if it were a currency value, that would be a different matter.

Comment: We will be billing by these weights, and I was also hoping to use jscience to hold units of the dimensions currency/mass.

Comment: @JonSkeet Try measuring a sum of money which requires 15+ digits of precision, precisely. ;)

Comment: @Mikey One way around this is to use fixed precision as a multiple of the minimum quantity/prices. e.g. use a `long` and use currency in cents/pence (or hundredths with an upper limit of 80 quintillion dollars) or weight in micro-grams (upper limit 8 million tonnes).  You will have a defined representation error which is your minimum quantity.

Comment: @Mikey: If you're billing by this and need the *exact* value originally entered in decimal form, then `double` is inappapropriate to start with - because it *will* represent 3.01 and 3.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625 with the same value. If those should be billed by different amounts, then you've got a fundamental problem, surely.

Comment: @Jonskeet your advice to get "more fundamental" allowed me to see I should be using DecimalMeasure and not Amount.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 10 digits of precision, you need to round to that precision.  Even if you use BigDecimal you can avoid representation error, but sooner or later you will have to know how to deal with precision.

```
double d = 3.01;
System.out.println(d); // rounds the answer slightly
```

prints

```
3.01
```

There are many workarounds for representation and rounding error, however often the built in tools will deal with it for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that you cannot expect to always get the original number back since there are many numbers that map to the same float. For example, you cannot distinguish between these numbers:

```
3.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625
3.009999999999999786837179271969944238662
3.009999999999999786837179271
3.0099999999999997
3.01
```

However, Python has an interesting take on this: if you give it the number 3.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625, it will reply with 3.01:

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Nov 30 2011, 19:22:03) 
[GCC 4.6.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625
3.01
```

This is becauuse `3.01` is the shortest string that gives the same floating point number. In other words, it's the shortest `x` so that

```
float(repr(x)) == x
```

where `repr` is the Python function that turns an object into a string (here it turns `3.0099...` into `3.01`) and `float` converts a string to a float.

There are obvisouly many strings that will result in the same internal float, but this is the shortest and therefore "probably" what you meant.

This feature was [added in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features), as a backport of a Python 3.1 feature. It was [discussed in Issue1580](http://bugs.python.org/issue1580) and you should be able to find the code there and translate it into Java if you want.